# Python pandas: a groupby filter output differs if we run an aggregate function before

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I observe a behavior I cannot explain with the following example.

```
# here is my pandas version
print("pandas version: {}".format(pd.__version__))
# I create a test DataFrame
d = pd.DataFrame({'data': range(6), 'key': list('ABCABC')})
# I groupby the column 'key'
g = d.groupby('key')
# I filter with always True (not that useful, just for the example)
print(g.filter(lambda x: True))
g.sum()
print(g.filter(lambda x: True))
```

here is the output

```
pandas version: 0.20.2
   data key
0     0   A
1     1   B
2     2   C
3     3   A
4     4   B
5     5   C
   data
0     0
1     1
2     2
3     3
4     4
5     5
```

I don't understand why the column key is in the output in the first run of filter, whereas when running an aggregate function (here `g.sum()`) before the filter, the `key` column disappear. If I use the `as_index=False` for the groupby, then the column is correctly preserved (as expected).

It looks like the aggregate function somehow change the groupby object, whereas my understanding of the groupby object is that each function call return a new object (and do not modify the original groupby object).

Does anybody know what is the reason for this behavior.

Best,
Arnaud

Comment: Deleted my answer as it indeed does not explain why aggregate changes the original groupby object. It may be a bug actually, as I can't find the description of this behavior in pandas api.

Comment: reported this issue in https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/17091 and it seems it has been confirmed as a bug.